# Doctrine and left join with condition

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I have a problem in the relationship when I use condition. My Post entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=User::class, inversedBy="posts")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
 */
private $user;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="smallint", nullable=true)
 */
private $type;
```

and User entity

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=Post::class, mappedBy="user")
 */
private $posts;
```

The problem exists when the repository uses this condition:

```
return $this->createQueryBuilder('p')
    ->addSelect('p', 'u', 'up')
    ->leftJoin('p.user', 'u')
    ->leftJoin('u.posts', 'up', 'WITH', 'p.type = up.type')
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult()
;
```

With such data in the database [image.png](https://github.com/lolen/doctrine-problem/blob/master/database.png?raw=true)

I get these [results](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lolen/doctrine-problem/master/result.json). In the first post, for the user the posts should be of the same type. (there should be no posts with id 3 and 5). If I use `getArrayResult()` instead of `getQuery()`, everything works fine, but I need entities. So it's probably due to optimization. Does anyone know how to deal with it?

Additionally adds [github source](https://github.com/lolen/doctrine-problem)

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use [Criteria to filter your collection](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/working-with-associations.html#filtering-collections) (and add the necessary filters on the join performed by the ORM when mapping the data not when calling the method in the repository).

You can find a hands-on example of Criteria usage in Symfony [here](https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/doctrine-relations/collection-criteria) (even the video is not available you do have the code and the explanations).

In the end, moving the `WITH` condition from the join (correct from the SQL standpoint) to a Criteria (useful with the ORM) should solve the problem you are having.